# how can I Cite the DSM if BibDesk does not allow for the proper format?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, bibdesk

I would like to cite in my list of References DSM III, however, none of the format in BibDesk would work! The problem is not how to cite Dsm III in APA, but what type of BibDesk entry("Manual" would not work) should I use to produce the proper outcome.I am using BibDesk Version 1.6.1 (2861).

Comment: Can you make clearer the subject?

Comment: The DSM (any edition) is a book. [Western Washington University's library has some information on how the final result should look in APA format.](http://askus.library.wwu.edu/a.php?qid=104554) You can probably figure out the BibTeX fields from there. Otherwise, a MWE including your BibTeX style would be helpful for further answers.

Comment: Do I have to ask another question ? The comment box won't allow me to paste any screen shot?

Comment: @giancarloDiano You can edit your question. But better than a screen shot, I think you need to tell us what fields you think are missing, and what bibliography package you are using to format references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike Renfro mentioned in his comment, you should use the `book` entry. Here's a screen shot of my BibDesk entry input for the DSM:

[image: screenshot from BiBDesk]

And here's a sample APA document.  I've used `biblatex` with the APA style, but if you are using `bibtex` with a different style it should still work.

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{apa-test-bib.bib} % change to your actual bib file

\title{An Example Document}
\shorttitle{Psychology: the end}
\author{Silly Name} 
\authornote{\dots}
\abstract{\dots}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is an example citation \parencite{American-Psychiatric-Association2000}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]